# a small corrrection needed in jquery code snippet. . along with a small query

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is this fiddle which is giving me not the desired output

http://jsfiddle.net/8FXFE/1/

The jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log("parsed");
$("input[name='txtNumber']").change(function () {
    console.log("changed");
    if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '100') $("#output").text("Changed to 100");
    else if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '200') $("#output").text("Changed to 200");
    else if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '500') $("#output").text("Changed to 500");
    else if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '1000') $("#output").text("Changed to 1000");
    else if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '10000') $("#output").text("Changed to 10000");
    else($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == 'other')
    $("#output").text("Changed to Other");
});
});
```

the desired output is that it shall show which radio button is clicked

Also I have a question?

1. What is the meaning of this line??

   ```
   console.log("parsed");
   ```

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Comment: Check my answer. You forgot the `if` in the last `else if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You forgot the `if` in the `else if` and just wrote `else (condition)`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log("parsed");
$("input[name='txtNumber']").change(function () {
    console.log("changed");
    if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '100') $("#output").text("Changed to 100");
    else if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '200') $("#output").text("Changed to 200");
    else if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '500') $("#output").text("Changed to 500");
    else if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '1000') $("#output").text("Changed to 1000");
    else if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '10000') $("#output").text("Changed to 10000");
    else($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == 'other')
//-----^-----------------//
// Forgot the if here!!! //
///////////////////////////

    $("#output").text("Changed to Other");
});
});
```

#### Change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log("parsed");
$("input[name='txtNumber']").change(function () {
    console.log("changed");
    if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '100') $("#output").text("Changed to 100");
    else if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '200') $("#output").text("Changed to 200");
    else if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '500') $("#output").text("Changed to 500");
    else if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '1000') $("#output").text("Changed to 1000");
    else if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == '10000') $("#output").text("Changed to 10000");
    else if ($("input[name='txtNumber']:checked").val() == 'other')
    $("#output").text("Changed to Other");
});
});
```

And it works!!!

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8FXFE/3/

---

#### What is `console.log`:

For your question. `console.log()` is a modern browser specific function, which prints anything inside the parentheses, to the JavaScript console.

[image]
<sub>(source: [tmont.com](http://jarvis.tmont.com/console-chrome.png))</sub>

Comment: check his fiddle it's a radio input

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have a question.. It is related to same code.. this radio already have some values like 100, 200, 300 etc.
suppose i have another radio with values in text. And i want to do calculation based on user's selection of those above mentioned (100, 200 etc) radio and this other radio (text values).
What will be the basis of that calculation? Mean how can i pull data in jquery or javascript to calculate something?

Comment: At a time only one radio can be selected. And yeah, I don't understand what you asked.

Comment: @PraveenKumar What i asked is that suppose i have two type of radio buttons..
1. 1st set of Radio buttons with value 100, 200, 300 and so on
2. 2nd set of Radio buttons with value a, b, c, d and so on
Now at some place i want to make a formula based on users selection of any option from 1 and any option from 2.. How can i make it?
For ex suppose the user select 100 from 1st set of radio and b from 2nd set of radio.. Now i need a formula in jquery that calculate based on those option he selects.. how can i make it??

Comment: Yeah, what is the formula? You need to manipulate strings or something like b has a value of 20 or something like that. Yes it is possible.

Comment: @PraveenKumar formula can be any.. i want to know the method of how can i make it..

Also check this fiddle.. I have a question regarding the same
http://jsfiddle.net/8FXFE/4/
when the page is loaded the output shows nothing.. while it shall show something initially also.. why not it show??

Comment: @PraveenKumar i solved earlier question of not showing any output by mentioning a default value inside the div, and on clicking on buttons it is changed automatically. now can u answer my previous question?

Comment: this succession of if is really ugly; and if mentioning you have to get back to the code every time you change the html then it is very very very ugly

Comment: @mikakun what do u suggest then??

Comment: @Sumit Seriously? What's the difference between my answer and his?

Comment: @Sumit there is my answer down there, why checking the radio value against its value ? doesn't make sense, use the value then create an exception for other to get the other input value (if you make calculation from that value)

Answer (score 1):

The [switch block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) can easify your overly complicated if-else block

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=txtNumber]").change(function () {
        switch($(this).val()) {
            case '100': $("#output").text("Changed to 100"); break;
            case '200': // and so on...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have a question.. It is related to same code.. this radio already have some values like 100, 200, 300 etc.
suppose i have another radio with values in text. And i want to do calculation based on user's selection of those above mentioned (100, 200 etc) radio and this other radio (text values).
What will be the basis of that calculation? Mean how can i pull data in jquery or javascript to calculate something?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='txtNumber']").change(function () {

    $("#output").text("Changed to "+$("input[name='txtNumber']:radio:checked").val());
});
```

edit sorry too fast you have to use the :checked indeed

edit 2: do a console.log(this) to see if you can get direct access to the value instead of making an access to the dom to get it :

i'm guessing

```
 this.target
```

should contain the value

console.log is to log your object/string/array in the console so to debug any problem

Comment: What indicates that the checkbox was checked and not unchecked?

Comment: it's a radio button not a checkbox; @Stefan you'd know if you had looked at the fiddle...

Comment: I have a question.. It is related to same code.. this radio already have some values like 100, 200, 300 etc.
suppose i have another radio with values in text. And i want to do calculation based on user's selection of those above mentioned (100, 200 etc) radio and this other radio (text values).
What will be the basis of that calculation? Mean how can i pull data in jquery or javascript to calculate something?

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
$("input[name='txtNumber']").change(function () {
    var $radio = $(this),
        $output = $('#output'),
        value = $radio.val() || $('#customNumber').val();

    if (value)
        $("#output").text("Changed to " + value);
    else
        $("#output").text("Changed to empty value");
});

$("#customNumber").keyup(function() {
    $("#output").text("Changed to " + $(this).val());
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="textForm">
    <input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="100" />100
    <input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="200" />200
    <input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="500" />500
    <input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="1000" />1000
    <input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="10000" />10000
    <input type="radio" name="txtNumber" value="" />other
    <input type="text" name="customNumber" id="customNumber" />
</div>

<h3>Output:</h3>

<div id="output"></div>
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/st3fan/tg32Q/)

Comment: I have a question.. It is related to same code.. this radio already have some values like 100, 200, 300 etc.
suppose i have another radio with values in text. And i want to do calculation based on user's selection of those above mentioned (100, 200 etc) radio and this other radio (text values).
What will be the basis of that calculation? Mean how can i pull data in jquery or javascript to calculate something?

Comment: Are you trying to distinguish numbers from strings? Have a look at parseInt; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt